Adding an image to a Tkinter button: why is the button blank?
I have read the previous posts about adding an image, and copied the code, altering the variable names for my own code. I get a blank button.
I am showing a canvas where I have plotted some graphics. The buttons are for zooming in and out, and are in a bar across the top of the canvas, in 'frame1'. The buttons are visible, the zoom function works, but the image does not display on the button - it's just a blank gray square.
Here is the code:
    frame1:Frame = Frame(self.root,border=2, height=45, width=800)
    frame1.place(x=600,y=1)

    upArrow = PhotoImage(file = r"C:/Users/JohnG/source/Python/TopArrow.png")
    downArrow = PhotoImage(file = r"C:/Users/JohnG/source/Python/BottomArrow.png")

    btnZoomIn:Button = Button(frame1,text='+',command=ZoomIn,font=('Consolas',12),image=downArrow)
    btnZoomIn.pack(side=LEFT)

    btnRecenter:Button = Button(frame1,text='X',command=Recenter,font=('Consolas',12))
    btnRecenter.pack(side=LEFT)

    btnZoomout:Button = Button(frame1,text='-',command=ZoomOut,font=('Consolas',12),image=upArrow)
    btnZoomout.pack(side=LEFT)

    btnReset:Button = Button(frame1,text='0',command=ResetMap,font=('Consolas',12))
    btnReset.pack(side=LEFT)

I get just a blank button where I assigned an image. The buttons with text show as expected, but I want to use images.
Also, why do I have to give the entire path to the image? If I don't, I get an 'image not found' error. I don't have to do that to import a module in the same directory.
Sorry if this is trivial to you, or if I've posted to the wrong group. I've tried everything I can find, but I can't get it to work.
(for what it's worth, I've coded professionally in C, C#, VB, and assembler for 3 different microprocessors. I'm not a noob, except in Python. This kind of thing in Python has been very frustrating.)
I've tried jpgs, bmps, other file formats. It only 'finds' png images for some reason.
You can see that I used text for the two other buttons, which works as expected. I guess I could try wingdings or some other special font. But I want to use images in other places, so I would like to get this to work.
